# Best frequent itemset package in python

Tags: python, association-rules

Could anyone please recommend a good frequent itemset package in python? I only need to find frequent itemset, no need of finding the association rules.

Comment: In my personal exp, I found R's apriori and FP-growth much better than their Python alternatives. So, if you're open to considering R, you should try them :)

Answer (score 11):

I also recommend [MLXtend](http://rasbt.github.io/mlxtend/user_guide/frequent_patterns/apriori/.) library for frequent itemsets.

#### usage example:

```
dataset = [['Milk', 'Onion', 'Nutmeg', 'Kidney Beans', 'Eggs', 'Yogurt'],
           ['Dill', 'Onion', 'Nutmeg', 'Kidney Beans', 'Eggs', 'Yogurt'],
           ['Milk', 'Apple', 'Kidney Beans', 'Eggs'],
           ['Milk', 'Unicorn', 'Corn', 'Kidney Beans', 'Yogurt'],
           ['Corn', 'Onion', 'Onion', 'Kidney Beans', 'Ice cream', 'Eggs']]

te = TransactionEncoder()

te_ary = te.fit(dataset).transform(dataset)

df = pd.DataFrame(te_ary, columns=te.columns_)

frequent_itemsets = apriori(df, min_support=0.1, use_colnames=True)

print frequent_itemsets
```

Comment: this package has memory error when you have too many distinct items. Not recommended for Big Data

Answer (score 4):

[Orange3-Associate](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Orange3-Associate) package provides [`frequent_itemsets()`](https://orange3-associate.readthedocs.io/en/latest/scripting.html#fpgrowth.frequent_itemsets) function based on [FP-growth](https://www.cs.sfu.ca/~jpei/publications/dami03_fpgrowth.pdf) algorithm.

Answer (score 3):

MLXtend library has been really useful for me. In its docummentation there is an Apriori implementation that outputs the frequent itemset.

Please check the first example available in  http://rasbt.github.io/mlxtend/user_guide/frequent_patterns/apriori/.